# How to control interaction between 2 classes (A & B) from 2 different assemblies?

Tags: c#, generics, access-modifiers

I have an assembly (X), it is a library called DataItems, which contains my Model, with classes that represent business Objetcts like Order, Invoice, etc.. They all inherit from Class DataItem (A). A has method ResetStatus (M).

X is used by different other projects, so I can't change that much about this.

I have an assembly, a library called DataContext (Y) which references assembly X. It handles Database Connections etc. and instantiates objects of class A, fills them with Data from different sources etc. It must be able to call A.Resetstatus() (M).

Basically, I want all my front-end assemblies to reference and use DataContext (Y). But I don't want them to be able to use M.

Comment: [abstract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract)?

Comment: What is method M? Could you add some pseudo-code of what you are trying to do?

Comment: You don't. If B is essentially a private class for A, why are they in different assemblies? I would move M to A and make it reference data in B

Comment: use access modifier

Comment: please elaborate more

Comment: It simply isn't possible. To be able to access a method in another assembly, the only available access modifiers are `public`, `protected` and `protected internal`. As your B class doesn't inherit from you A class, you have only one choice: `public`. And if it's `public`, it's accessible from everywhere.

Comment: You could consider a Roslyn analyser or what not so you get warnings if certain things access certain methods, that _may_ be sufficient for your needs?

Comment: Thanks for the tip @krimog, I hadn't thought of using inheritance.

Comment: @A.Non Inheritance isn't for accessibility. You should not try to hide the method (as there is no clean way to do it), but try to make it so a call from anywhere else wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an interface to expose just the methods that you choose.

```
public interface IDataItem 
{
    void OnlyUseThis();
}

public class DataItem : IDataItem
{
    public void OnlyUseThis()
    {  
        // externaly available
    }

    public void ResetStatus()
    {
        // hands off
    }
}
```

Don't use DataItem externally, use IDataItem instead.

Programmers will be able to get to the implementation if they really want to, but not by chance.

Comment: This works and answers the question, so I marked it as an answer. Thx to you and to @krimog for pointing out the flaws in my concept.